# How can I check Delivery Status of campaign on Facebook Marketing API

Tags: python, facebook-marketing-api

I'm doing a little app on Python about this. I was using the "effective_status" field but  it shows just if it's paused or not, and I want to check if the campaign is running or not.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is also asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632685/fb-ads-api-status-effective-status-and-the-ads-actual-status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effective_status gives you the effective status of this campaign.
For Campaign object, effective_status value can be one of these

```
ACTIVE, PAUSED, DELETED, PENDING_REVIEW, DISAPPROVED, PREAPPROVED, PENDING_BILLING_INFO, CAMPAIGN_PAUSED, ARCHIVED, ADSET_PAUSED
```

If you read the effective_status field for adset level, it will tell you if the adset has CAMPAIGN_PAUSED or PAUSED.

**EDIT:**
**You will need to combine this field with end_time to determine whether the ad set is completed.**

Comment: In fact that status is not the delivery status that you can see from the facebook AdManager. Often the status stay `ACTIVE` but the delivery status is `Not delivering Adset completed`.
I also didn't find in the API how to get this `Delivery status`

Comment: The `effective_status` represent **The effective status of the ad set, which can be either its own status or caused by its parent campaign.**, said by Facebook. You should combine this with the delivery time to determine whether the ad set is delivering.

Comment: Not working for me too :( Both configured and effective status are "Active" for both Ad and AdSet, however FB online AdManager says that they aren't delivering due to being in review... In the source code I found "PENDING_REVIEW" option of "EffectiveStatus", but it never appears. Why the SDK isn't working?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter ads by ad-recommendation field. That can solve some of the delivery issues notifications and act as a delivery field in addition with effective_status field https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-recommendation/