# Facebook Marketing API - Campaigns Ended?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

How can you realize from Facebook Marketing API which campaigns have ended?

Of course, you'll quickly check the `status` or `effective_status` field only to realize that ended campaigns are set to `ACTIVE` status.

I've already tried to fetch the elusive `is_completed` field with no luck.

I've also tried to use `delivery_info` with no avail.

What am I to do?

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is no attribute at the campaign level that will give you the delivery status (the one you can see in the Ads Manager).

The only way to get this status is to compute it by yourself by analyzing all adset in the campaign. You can check this Stackoverflow question that give some advices (but I think it could be great if this info could be available directly in the API):
[How can I check Delivery Status of campaign on Facebook Marketing API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130309/how-can-i-check-delivery-status-of-campaign-on-facebook-marketing-api#comment76867923_42130309)